# How to redirect inside `each` loop without error?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

When user click to $clickableCardEl it redirects to another page

```
it('cards should not to redirect to 404 page', () => {
    cy.getByCyId('clickable-card').each($clickableCardEl => {
      cy.wrap($clickableCardEl).click().wait(3000);
      cy.getByCyId('not-found-content').should('not.exist');
      cy.go('back');
    });
  });
```

And I get this error

> cy.click() failed because the page updated as a result of this
> command, but you tried to continue the command chain. The subject is
> no longer attached to the DOM, and Cypress cannot requery the page
> after commands such as cy.click().

I want to iterate all $clickableCardEl inside each loop and click on them.

Comment: Why _are_ you continuing the command? Use the implicit wait on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I want to iterate all $clickableCardEl inside each loop...***  - it's not possible, the page refreshes with each click.

***I want to test all cards should not to redirect to 404 page*** - it's possible because you can use `cy.request()` to test links.

```js
const failedCards = []

cy.getByCyId('clickable-card').each($clickableCardEl => {
  cy.wrap($clickableCardEl).invoke('attr', 'href')
    .then((href) => {
      cy.request({ url: href, failOnStatusCode: false})
        .then(res => {
          if (res.status === 404) {
            failedCards.push($clickableCardEl)
          }
        })
    })
})
.then(() => {
  cy.wrap(failedCards).should('have.length', 0)   // or print the failed items
})
```

Answer (score -1):

try following

```
it('cards should not redirect to 404 page', () => {
      cy.getByCyId('clickable-card').each(($clickableCardEl) => {
        cy.location('pathname').then((initialPathname) => {
          cy.wrap($clickableCardEl).click().wait(3000);
    
          cy.location('pathname').then((newPathname) => {
            if (initialPathname !== newPathname && newPathname === '/404') {
              cy.log('Card led to 404 page');
            } else {
              cy.log('Card did not lead to 404 page');
            }
    
            cy.go('back');
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Please add an explanation for _why_ this should work - providing example code without an explanation of how it solves their problem doesn't help OP learn, or help those in the future figure out if this problem/solution is applicable to their case.